# Showing a sequence converges weakly.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$. How can I show that the sequence ${g_n}$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $g_n(x) = f(x − n)$?

If this is not true could someone provide a counter example as to why not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, and for $n\in\mathbb N$, $g_n(x)=f(x-n)$. Since $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is a reflexive space,

> $g_n\rightharpoonup 0$

is equivalent to:

> For any $h\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, $\int g_n(x)h(x)dx \to 0$

Choose $h\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\int_{\mathbb R\backslash B(0,R)}h^2\to 0$ as $R\to+\infty$, choose $R>0$ such that
$$
\Vert h\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R\backslash B(0,R))}<\varepsilon.
$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int g_n(x)h(x)dx &= \int_{\mathbb R\backslash B(0,R)} g_n(x)h(x)dx+\int_{B(0,R)} g_n(x)h(x)dx \\
&\leq \Vert g_n\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R\backslash B(0,R))}\Vert h\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R\backslash B(0,R))}+\Vert g_n\Vert_{L^2(B(0,R))}\Vert h\Vert_{L^2(B(0,R))}\\
&\leq \varepsilon \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}+\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(B(n,R))}\Vert h\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}
\end{align*}

Once again, using the fact that $\int_{\mathbb R\backslash B(0,R)}f^2\to 0$ as $R\to+\infty$, choose $n$ such that $\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(B(n,R))}< \varepsilon$ to conclude.